# How set password in scrapinghub/splash docker installation?

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm using the `splash` on an ubuntu server and followed the instructions to install with docker (https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

```
docker run -p 8050: 8050 scrapinghub / splash
```

How can I change the settings and set username and password?

Comment: This question is old, but I solved using LoadBalancer (HAproxy) to set http access authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium) with the `auth_user` and `auth_password` options.

This is described in [How to run Splash in production?](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-run-splash-in-production), from the [Splash FAQ](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to integrating Aquarium-Splash and Scrapy, the user and password could be passed under `scrapy crawl` using the `-a` option as per [official documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html) of Scrapy.